# Filling area bounded by several lines and adding a text

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, fill

I'm very new to Tex and trying to draw a graph using tikz package.

So here's the code I wrote

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\ifx\du\undefined
  \newlength{\du}
\fi
\setlength{\du}{15\unitlength}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgftransformxscale{1}
\pgftransformyscale{-1}
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.1\du}
\draw (0\du,0\du)--(13\du,-13\du);
\draw (0\du,0\du)--(4\du,-1\du);
\draw (4\du,-1\du)--(9\du,-5\du);
\draw (9\du,-5\du)--(11\du,-8\du);
\draw (11\du,-8\du)--(13\du,-13\du);
\node[anchor=west] at (7\du,-5\du){some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to fill the area bounded by these lines and also have that "some text" visible.

Could someone help, please?

Comment: Your code is strange - mixing low(lower) level code `\pgf...` with high level code. Where did you get that idea? - do you need it for some reason?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't know what any of those terms mean :) I'm just trying to have a neat graph using tikz.

Comment: You're drawing a non continuous path which is not the best way to achieve what you seem to want. It could also be better if you let a drawing of the needed output because it's not easy to understand as is. Why this low level pgf code when it can be achived in a simple way in Ti*k*Z? And why those *transform shape* to simply draw lines that could be drawn with accurate coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can understand what you're looking for, here's a solution, getting rid of these unneeded low level pgf lines and modifying y coordinates accordingly to avoid this *y transform shape*.

[image: filling area]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \ifx\du\undefined
      \newlength{\du}
    \fi
    \setlength{\du}{15\unitlength}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=0.1\du, fill=pink] (0\du,0\du)--(13\du,13\du) -- (11\du,8\du) -- (9\du,5\du) -- (4\du,1\du) -- cycle;
        \node at (7\du,5\du){some text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\du}{15pt}
\draw[fill=cyan,very thick] (0,0) -- (13*\du,13*\du) -- (11*\du,8*\du) -- (9*\du,5*\du)  -- (4*\du,\du) -- cycle;
\node[anchor=west, red, font=\large] at (7*\du,5*\du){some text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: cyan shape with text]